# How to copy selected columns and filter them before hand in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am just a beginner in VBA. I am trying to copy some data from one workbook that is updated daily to a master woorkbook and generate a report. I want it to first filter one of the columns for nonzero values and copy it with three selected columns for example columns T,C,N. I have looked everywhere for an answer but I haven't succeeded yet. Please help.

Comment: You should start by using macro recorder. It should do 90% of needed work.

Comment: I have.. but when I filter it, the size changes and i get an error message if  I start a new session.

Comment: So you have some code already? Then show it here. What error you get? At which line of your code? Unfortunately, my magic glass ball is broken, so I can''t read code from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a given cell has value 0 by something like this `If Sheets(sheetname).Cells(rownumber,columnnumber)=0 Then`

You haven't specified what do you want to do on the other workbooks with the cells that were empty.